# Identifier '....' is not defined. '__type' does not contain such a member Angular FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using the reactive form to create multiple checkboxes  with FormArray but when I use it in my template got this error:

> Identifier 'roleNames' is not defined. '__type' does not contain such
>   a memberAngular

this is my htmlCode:

```html
<form [formGroup]="createUserFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <label formArrayName="roleNames"
        *ngFor="let role of createUserFormGroup.controls.roleNames.controls; let i = index">
        <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
        {{role[i].displayName}}
    </label>
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

This is my typescript code:

```js
constructor(
public _userService: UserServiceProxy,
private _ouServiceProxy: OuServiceProxy,
private managetableService: ManageTablesService<UserDto>,
private formBuilder: FormBuilder) 
{
this.createUserFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  'roleNames': new FormArray([]),
});  }

    this._userService.getRoles().subscribe(result => {
  this.roles = result["result"].items;
  this.addRoleCheckBoxes();
  // this.setInitialRolesStatus();
});

  addRoleCheckBoxes() {
debugger;
this.roles.map((roleDto, index) => {
  const control = new FormControl(index === 0);
  (this.createUserFormGroup.controls.roleNames as FormArray).push(control);
});
```

Comment: Try this. *ngFor="let role of createUserFormGroup.controls.roleNames?.controls;

Comment: I try this but unfortunately not work this trick

Comment: Try to reproduce the error on stackblitz. Your code is working for me in local.

Answer (score 1):

your *ngFor should be like this

```
*ngFor="let role of createUserFormGroup.get('roleNames')['controls']; let i = index"
```

Not like this

```
*ngFor="let role of createUserFormGroup.controls.roleNames.controls; let i = index"
```

And to use dynamic array

```
<div [formGroupName]="i">
   <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="your control name"> // not the index of the arra
    {{role[i].displayName}}
</div>
```

[image: Working code]

Comment: hello MuruGan i try this in my *ngFor but i get error:Parser Error: Unexpected token (, expected identifier or keyword at column 37 in [let role of createUserFormGroup.get.(roleNames).[controls]; let i = index]

Comment: Again sorry. See my updated with an image. It's my working code in my proj

Answer (score 1):

Try to Update your HTML as following:

```
<form [formGroup]="createUserFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <label [formGroup]="role"
        *ngFor="let role of createUserFormGroup.controls.roleNames.controls; let i = index">
        <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
        {{role[i].displayName}}
    </label>
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I define formArray in my typescript

Answer (score 0):

I find my problem

I must change this code with roles

```
{{roles[i].displayName}}
```

no 
    {{role[i].displayName}}

in fact, in formArray we only have the count of formControls no values of checkbox and we have to add value from another place